# Python: How do I get <div> background-image url value

Tags: python

Currently I'm using the below code to get all img tags on the page.
Can I somehow access the  background-img url value

```
import random
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#1. Reading pages
source = requests.get("https://www.dummie-website/photos_all").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

    enter code here

#2. Getting every 'src' value from all img tags
match = [x['src'] for x in soup.findAll('img', {'class': ''})]

for i in match:
  print(i)
```

Comment: we need the actual/target html sample and explanation of what isn't working with your code.

Comment: The above is currently succeeding with finding all <img/> tags on a page and extract the src={value}.
However, what I need is some way to get  <div/> background - images.
Let's say you want to download all of your FB images html structure should not matter.